# A case for matrix multiplication (a.b).c unequal to a.(b.c) in mathematica 12.0.0.0, why?

Tags: matrix, numerics, inverse

The motivation of my calculation is to get the inverse for the following matrix

```
c={{806187941679782.0, 218884444558405.0, -44574352.7996484, 
  263790009.291711, -7043899062155.16 , 101619269971218.0},
 {218884444558405.0, 59429013469996.9, -12139526.3237759, 
  71717183.1728141, -1913730353321.76, 27580785304831.0},
 {-44574352.7996484, -12139526.3237759, 
  5.06604715779434, -20.0242999918957, 
  455028.9823731, -5189609.42411989},
 {263790009.291711, 71717183.1728141, -20.0242999918957, 
  100.006624596537, -2482688.13923785, 31962666.0977317},
 {-7043899062155.16, -1913730353321.76, 
  455028.9823731, -2482688.13923785 , 
  63930635211.802, -869762434934.025},
 {101619269971218.0, 27580785304831.0, -5189609.42411989, 
  31962666.0977317, -869762434934.025, 12957503435300.3}}
```

A direct "b=Inverse[c]" gives the following warning

```
Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix (<<1>>) may contain significant numerical errors.
```

Not surprisingly, the diverge of "b.c" from the identity matrix is large. Then I try to use the matrix

```
a=Inverse[Inverse[c].c]
```

as a correction. The new Inverse is "a.b". When I test the new inverse, Mathematica gives the following results
[image]

which are obviously different.

Why do this happen? Besides, is there any better way to perform the matrix inversion in this case?

Comment: there is no `m` matrix. I assume you meant `c` instead of `m` everywhere. But let me make sure I understand. You are using outputs that Mathematica says `may contain significant numerical errors` and then wondering why the result of `(a.b).c` is different from `a.(b.c.)` ? is it possible they are different result due to these numerical errors?

Comment: `is there any better way to perform the matrix inversion` why are you trying to do matrix inverse in first place. Normally this is not needed, unless for academic exercise. Are you try to solve a system of equations?

Comment: Thanks for you reminding. I meant "c" when I use "m". The only operation involves the "significant numerical errors" is "b=Inverse[c]", while the operation "(a.b).c" and "a.(b.c)" gives no warning. It may be possible that the numerical errors in "b" cause such difference. But I hope to make things clear. @Nasser

Comment: One of my friends give me the matrix and ask for the inversion, I do not know his motivation.@Nasser

Comment: You can check the condition number of the matrix before doing inverse. Your `c` matrix has very large condition number, which is not good for inverse. `LUDecomposition[c][[3]]` gives `2.90361*10^21`. This is practically a singular matrix. Condition number should be small. less than 100 at most.  but this really depends. I do not think there is a fixed number to look for, but the smaller it is, the better for inversion.

Comment: What's the condition number?@Nasser

Comment: condition number is measure how many digits in accuracy one can lose when doing an operation,. From Wikipedia `A problem with a low condition number is said to be well-conditioned, while a problem with a high condition number is said to be ill-conditioned.`  so always better to check the condition number of a matrix before doing matrix inverse. But again, in real applications, there is no need to do direct matrix inversion any way. May be ask your friend why they want to calculate $A^{-1}$ for.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot.@Nasser

Comment: Instead of the Inverse for badly conditioned matrices, the "PseudoInverse", also called "Moore\[Dash]Penrose inverse" is used. Look it up in the help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The PseudoInverse give me a better result. Now max diverge of the "b.c" from identity matrix is only 0.0004. @DanielHuber

Comment: Sorry, I found that there are some big error in the diagonal terms.@DanielHuber

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need the inverse. If you have a badly conditioned matrix it is often better to use another method (if possible).